# High capacitance electrical capacitors

Tags: energy, capacitance, batteries

Are high capacitance electrical capacitors capable of storing energy instead of using a battery. 
If so would they be able to hold 7 kws of usable energy for domestic home use?

Comment: Yes, but probably not at a cost anyone might consider sensible.

Comment: Afaik their capacitance is only a few Farad. In addition they have a low voltage rating. Thus I think they are not useful for the purpose you have in mind.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: They might soon become a reality: http://spectrum.ieee.org/semiconductors/materials/how-a-microscopic-supercapacitor-will-supercharge-mobile-electronics

Comment: This is a rather silly question since a minute doing the math to see how large the capacitor needs to be would provide the answer.

Answer (score 2):

These are supercapacitors you are talking about. A lithium ion battery of the same energy capacity will both cost and weigh 10% as much or less. Capacitors are therefore only considered where power density is of concern (how fast you need the energy to be available, such as in high intensity camera flash units or electric detonators for explosives for example), in which case chemical batteries can't compare.

For home use, slow, steady and sustained is key, so electrochemical storage is here to stay for many years. Not to mention $$$.

Answer (score 1):

Capacitors store energy, so of course it is possible in the sense that no laws of physics are violated.  To decide whether it is practical, do the math.  It really should have been obvious to do this in the first place.

The energy stored in a capacitor is:

E = C V<sup>2</sup> / 2

The capacitance to store a specific energy at a specific voltage is therefore:

C = 2 E / V<sup>2</sup>

The energy you want to store is 7 kWs, or 7 kJ.  You say this is to back up power to a house, so let's say 200 V.  So we have:

C = 2(7 kJ)/(200 V)<sup>2</sup> = 350 mF

Now figure the electronic circuit that converts power from the capacitor into a normal power line sine can deal with a 2:1 voltage range, which means only 3/4 of the energy in the cap is accessible.  Now you need 470 mF.  The circuit will have some loss.  Let's say it is 75% efficient, so now you need 620 mF.

That won't be cheap or small, and would be realized by a bank of smaller capacitors in parallel.  I just looked around, and [here](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/United-Chemi-Con/ELXA250LGC393TC80M/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsh%252b1woXyUXj%252bogjBqnhb14Pe7BdxCsDu8%3d) is a possible capacitor.  It's rated at 250 V, 39 mF, and costs $10.50 each in lots of 100.  You'd need about 20 of them in parallel to get 620 mF minimum taking tolerance into account.  That's $210 of capacitors, although this particular item on Mouser has a 100 unit minimum order quantity and is non-stocked.  If this is supposed to be a product, then you work out a deal with the manufacturer directly.

However, 7 kWs isn't much energy for a whole house.  That's 700 W for 10 seconds, 117 W for a minute, or just 2 W for one hour.  Most houses draw more than 2 W even when everything is "off", so this level of backup energy isn't good for more than riding out a few seconds of power glitch.  It would address the problem of a tree branch falling and shorting the power lines, the breaker tripping, then resetting in a few seconds.  Beyond that it's not of much use.

Comment: I suspect the OP didn't actually mean kilowatt-seconds.

Comment: @Simon: We only know what he wrote, and there is no evidence in there that he meant anything other than what he wrote.  I assume he's thinking of riding out a auto-resettable breaker event.  We have those around here occasionally.

Comment: You could be right.  My guess was that it was meant to be 7kWh - about the size of the home battery banks that Tesla are developing.

Comment: Almost verbatim the answer that sprang to mind when I saw the question!

Answer (score 1):

Graphene Super Capacitors are on the verge of breaking commercially.
There are claims they will be a lot cheaper than Tesla's Lithium Ion Battery and provide the 7 kws of energy you are looking for at $100 per Kw. Sunvault is curently building a smart phone case that will use them and charge a phone in 5 minutes and run your phone for the day. They also have a planned super capacitor set up for your solar panels. It is hard to say exactly how far off these are but let's be hopeful.

They anticipate they will be smaller than the Li-ion batteries and have as much storage density and power density for running a home.

http://www.sunvaultenergy.com/web20/

https://vimeo.com/51873011

http://www.sunvaultenergy.com/web20/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Super-Capacitor-EESD-update-2000-Farads-in-a-credit-card.mp4

http://spectrum.ieee.org/semiconductors/materials/how-a-microscopic-supercapacitor-will-supercharge-mobile-electronics